# Google Sheets VLOOKUP returning multiple values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with a key, value pairs where the key can occur multiple times. I want to find all values for given key e.g.

```
|A   |B      |
|Key1|Value11|
|Key2|Value2 |
|Key1|Value12|
```

I need a function like `vlookup` but I want to return every value matching given key e.g. `vlookup_multiple("Key1", "A:B", 2)` would return column "Value11", "Value12" or alternatively it can concatenate found values.

Is there such function or I need to write it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need **`QUERY`** for this task:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select B where A = '"&"Key1"&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

and for concatenating you can wrap it into **`JOIN`** or **`TEXTJOIN`**:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, QUERY(A:B, "select B where A = '"&"Key1"&"'", 0))
```